# Displaying Managed Property in Search Results

Tags: search, search-results, fast-for-sharepoint

We are working with Fast Search for Sharepoint 2010 and had some backend setup done with creating some managed properties e.g. BestBetDescription, keywords etc.

From the front-end part we are creating an application what will fetch all these properties and display in a grid.

However while querying the backend we are NOT getting these managed properties (BestBetDescription) along with other properties such as Title, URL etc.

Following is my source code:

```
 settingsProxy = SPFarm.Local.ServiceProxies.GetValue<SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy>();
 searchProxy = settingsProxy.ApplicationProxies.GetValue<SearchServiceApplicationProxy>("FAST Query SSA");
 keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(searchProxy);
 keywordQuery.EnableFQL = true;
 keywordQuery.QueryText = p;
 keywordQuery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.FASTSearch;
 keywordQuery.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
 ResultTableCollection resultsTableCollection = keywordQuery.Execute();
 ResultTable searchResultsTable = resultsTableCollection[ResultType.RelevantResults];
 DataTable resultsDataTable = new DataTable();
 resultsDataTable.TableName = "Results";
 resultsDataTable.Load(searchResultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
 return resultsDataTable;
```

The results are returned and I cannot see the Managed properties which we create in the resultDataTable.

Is there any property I missed or is this a backend issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting [KeywordQuery.SelectProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.keywordquery.selectproperties.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Per..!! this worked very well...!! Thanks again..!!